# Popup Manipulation WP8.1 C#

Tags: c#, popup, windows-phone-8.1, image-manipulation, popupwindow

i am currently trying to manipulate a Popup of an Image with the manipulation delta class.
I therefore can not figure out how to call the manipulation delta event.

I have found the solution on the web, but i am not able to implement it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/0c24865a-0d87-49dd-824b-cec250a4fb82/manipulation-delta-on-windows-8-popup-c

[manipulationdelta for popup window - XAML Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669536/manipulationdelta-for-popup-window-xaml-windows-8)

I do not know how i implement this grid, so that my manipulation delta event is called. I tried to include it to the popup via child and it is in front. (Checked by changing the color) but it does not respond to any manipulation events.

My code is visible below. The ctrlGrid is the one i am calling manipulation delta events with (ctrlgrid.ManipulationDelta and imagepopup.ManipulationDelta tried)

Thank you for any help regarding this.

Flo

```
 Grid popUpGrid = new Grid
        {
            MinHeight = imagePopup.ActualHeight,
            MinWidth = imagePopup.ActualWidth,
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green),
        };
       imagePopup.Child = popUpGrid;


       Image popUpImage = new Image           
            {
                Source = ((Image)sender).Source,
                //MaxHeight = popUpGrid.MinHeight,
            };
       popUpGrid.Children.Add(popUpImage); 

Grid ctrlGrid = new Grid
       {
           MinHeight=imagePopup.ActualHeight,
           MinWidth=imagePopup.ActualWidth,
           Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
           IsDoubleTapEnabled=true,
           ManipulationMode=ManipulationModes.All 

       };
       popUpGrid.Children.Add(ctrlGrid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the help of a colleague.
I was using the wrong deltamanipulation handler. I used the handler of the popup itself, whereas the ctrlGrid_Deltamanipulation handler was the correct one.

Flo